# get most recently selected listbox item from multiselect

Tags: c#, jquery, listbox

I've got a listbox of items where I allow multi select.
I am trying to get the latest most recent item selected, not the order value, but what the user selected last.

If I try to print out `.val()` I get a list of the selected values, but I want the most recent (the last one in val()).

I tried using `:last` like so:

`$("#MainContent_lbTeams option:selected:last").val();`

But last works on order of ID's from ascending to descending, doesnt work on time when someone selects a value.

For instance if I have a list box of 4 items.  If I select them in ascending order what I posted above prints correctly.  But if I click the 1st, then the 4th, and back to the 2nd what I posted above prints the 4th item (even though I most recently selected the 2nd one).

```
//when a team is selected
//tell the user what this does to the record
$("#MainContent_lbTeams").on('change', function () {
    //was a value selected?
    var latest_value = $("#MainContent_lbTeams option:selected:last").val();
    var latest_text = $("#MainContent_lbTeams option:selected:last").text();
    alert(latest_value);
    alert(latest_text);
    if ($("#MainContent_lbTeams :selected").length > 0) {
        $("#MainContent_lblTeamMembers").text("Members of '" + latest_text + "':");
        // act only when the returned promise is resolved
        PopulateMembers(latest_value).then(function () {
            $("#MainContent_lbMembers_chosen a").removeClass("search-choice-close");
        });
    }
});
```

Is there something else I can use to pick up the latest selected value of my multiselect listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something a bit different.
Given that the .val() for a multi select is stored as an array, I took the difference between the two arrays.  Here is what I ended up with:

```
            var myTeam = [];
        $("#trMembers").hide();
        $("#MainContent_lbTeams").on('change', function () {
            //was a value selected?
            //store the difference of what teams are selected vs myTeam[]
            var diff = [];
            jQuery.grep($("#MainContent_lbTeams").val(), function (el) {
                if (jQuery.inArray(el, myTeam) == -1) diff.push(el);
            });

            if (diff.length > 0) {
                var latest_value = diff; //has the latest selected value
                var latest_text = $("#MainContent_lbTeams option[value='" + diff + "']").text(); //stores the text
                if ($("#MainContent_lbTeams :selected").length > 0) {
                    $("#dTeamNotice").show();
                    $("#MainContent_lblTeamMembers").text("Members of '" + latest_text + "':");
                    // act only when the returned promise is resolved
                    PopulateMembers(latest_value).then(function () {
                        $("#MainContent_lbMembers_chosen a").removeClass("search-choice-close");
                        $("#trMembers").fadeIn();
                    });
                } else {
                    //hide it...
                    $("#dTeamNotice").css("display", "none");
                    $("#trMembers").hide();
                }
            }
            myTeam = $("#MainContent_lbTeams").val();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way but because it's multi you can find an array of objects for all the added ones in `added` and removed ones in `removed`.

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var latest_value = $(this).data('value') || {},
        latest_text = $(this).data('text') || {},
        new_value = {},
        new_text = {},
        added = [],
        removed = [];

    $("option:selected", this).each(function(){
        new_value[$(this).val()] = true;
        new_text[$(this).text()] = true;
        if($(this).val() in latest_value){
            delete latest_value[$(this).val()];
            delete latest_text[$(this).text()];
        }else{
            added.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        }
    });

    for(v in latest_value){
        removed.push({value: latest_value[v], text: latest_text[v]});
    }

    console.log('added', added);
    console.log('removed', removed);

    $(this).data({value: new_value, text: new_text});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7bfqdwd/1/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well for me...seems like this should be a lot simpler.  Isnt there any other way of getting the latest selected value?

Comment: @JonH what exactly doesn't work? Can you take a look at the demo and confirm that it is working correctly? You could store both values in data which would make it a little easier. I'll add that in a second.

Comment: The demo is using a single drop down.  I've got a multiselect allowing multiple choices.  Initially, when i select a value I get issues since there was no last value selected - since it is the first one.  You see I am trying to make an ajax call in populatemembers (code not shown for that).  And latest_value appears to be undefined, and then when I select a new value in the list box (since it is multi select) it updates the ajax code with the prior selection rather than the current selection...

Comment: @JonH I see your problem now, I miss read the multi part. I've updated my answer to compare the currently selected to the previous to return 2 different arrays 1 for added and one for removed. I also see you answered the question as well. Not sure if it's needed, but yours only takes for account of additions and not multiples. I'm not sure if multiple additions can occur before the change event, but multiple removals can.